Promise.race not firing reject promise
I am trying to use a Promise.race to forcebly timeout a function
With the setup below I would expect the code below to return "value b"; the method getValues takes more time to respond than the timeout so it should be discarded.
Running the code below I see that the function returns "value a" from the getValues method which takes longer then the timeout.
async function getDBValues(): Promise {
  let values = 'value b';

  try {
    values = await Promise.race([
      getValues(); // This returns successfully in about 30 ms with value a
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => reject(`rejected`), 1);
      });
    ]);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error ${error}`);
  }

  return values;
}

I already tried adjusting the timeouts, and using arrow functions.

What is getValues? Is it asynchronous, or does it have synchronous work to do that takes 30ms? Also, you cannot use a semi-colon after getValues(), nor after new Promise().

From your description, I  would guess that getValues() is not asynchronous, but is synchronous or returns a value, not a promise.  And, you need to use a comma after getValues(), not a semicolon.

It seems you lost interest in your question.
